# Установка промежутка для ЛКГ

Tags: алгоритм, случайные-числа

Мы имеем понятную рекуррентную формулу для получения каждого следующего элемента псевдослучайной последовательности (X(n+1) = (a*X(n) + C) % m). Так будут генерироваться числа в диапазоне [0;m-1]. Как можно установить пределы этой последовательности, например, в [a,b], если нельзя использоваться операцию взятия по модулю (%)?

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
Y = a + X * (b - a) / (m-1)
```

Это масштабирование диапазона  `0..m-1` на диапазон `0.. b-a` путём применения соответствующего коэффициента, затем сдвиг  на `a`, чтобы получить `a..b`

Comment: наверно, стоит хоть вкратце объяснить, как получена формула.

Comment: Да, было бы неплохо понять, как получилась эта формула

Comment: А, если, например, m = 64 бита, то m-1 максимально, которое может поместиться в тип данных. Как быть тогда, ведь, если так, то y = a будет получаться всегда

Comment: Если имеете в виду, что целочисленное деление приведёт тому, что второе слагаемое всегда 0, то сначала выполняется умножение, потом деление.

Comment: @MBo, я имею ввиду, если мы используем, к примеру, тип данных unsigned long long, который вмещает 8 байт. За m берем машинное слово, то есть 2 в 64, m-1 будет максимально возможным, x также является ull, тогда в любой ситуации может получится или 0, или 1, и числа будут лежать в диапазоне [a,a+1]

Comment: [muldiv64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733178/most-accurate-way-to-do-a-combined-multiply-and-divide-operation-in-64-bit)